# Authentication for Mongodb 3.4 is not validating the authentication properly using java, even I have given wrong credentials it got connected to DB

Tags: java, mongodb

MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );

```
  // Creating Credentials 
  MongoCredential credential; 
  credential = MongoCredential.createCredential("sampleUser", "myDb", 
     "password".toCharArray()); 
  System.out.println("Connected to the database successfully");
```

Comment: As pointed out in the below answer you need to make sure that MongoDb is started with `--auth` option. Have you done that?

Comment: Yes, I started with --auth option only again I am facing the same issue. I have given wrong username or password or db name incorrectly then also the it will connect. It doesn't through a msg like authentication failed.

Answer (score 1):

The MongoDB server instance is unauthenticated by default.

See the Mongo docs on how to [enable authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) if you wish to run it in secure mode.